# Google Maps API - click event only firing when edge clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, onclick, polygon

I have a Google map with a number of simple polygons each with click event to open an infowindow. Polygons are drawn on the map correctly, 'pointing-hand' cursor and click event fires and infowindow is shown correctly, but only when an edge is clicked. When the cursor moves inside the polygon it returns to 'pan-hand' and click event is not fired. I've researched Google Maps Polygon samples and have used similar functions previously - cannot figure this out...I'm sure something simple I'm overlooking - any ideas appreciated??

Comment: This [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays) works correctly for me.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: geocodezip - thanks for the response. I think I've found potential issue here - the polygon vertices are read from database and found there are many with some sides quite short. Either mathematical issue or too many sides? Further tested limited the number of vertices to 15 and internal click event now firing correctly.

Comment: can you post an example? When it's like said it would be a bug which should be reported,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue - not a bug and not a problem with code. I've found that the list of GIS coordinates read from the database was duplicated, i.e. there were 2 polygons being drawn with same coordinates. Interesting that graphically the polygon fill colour was displayed as expected but click event only fired when cursor was over an edge. Thanks for responses.